# Auto complete trigger for all alphabets in CDT Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-cdt

While using Java with Eclipse, I'm able to do auto activation by entering following in "auto activation triggers" :

.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Is there a way to do this in CDT?
In CDT, the only triggers available are ., -> and ::